# Probability Distribution of Employees

Tags: probability

Given: Distribution of employees as per gender and status

Male Part-time= 10; Male Probationary=15; Male Full-time=5

Female Part-time= 12; Female Probationary=8; Female Full-time=10

If a person is selected at random ,what is the probability of choosing a female full-time?

> My answer is 1/6 (10 out of 60) but using the multiplication rule (P female ∩ full-time)=P(female) x P(full-time) = (30/60)x(15/60), this gives 1/8. I got confused the rule on probability does not match with intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(female ∩ full-time)=P(female) x P(full-time) is only true if the events Female and Full-Time are independent, which they are not in your case.

You have to use the conditional probability:

P(female ∩ full-time) = P(female) * P(full-time | female) = P(full-time) * P(female | full-time)

The notation P(X | Y) means probability of having X knowing that there is Y.
So typically P(full-time | female) is the probability to pick a full-time knowing that this is a female. Hence P(full-time | female) = 10/30

Applied to your problem we have:

P(female ∩ full-time) = P(female) * P(full-time | female) = 30/60 * 10/30 = 1/6

Same with the other conditional probability:

P(female ∩ full-time) = P(full-time) * P(female | full-time) = 15/60 * 10/15 = 1/6

Comment: Oh I see.. so there can be no rule on probability to be applied on the problem except for looking at the given information?

Comment: I think the law you can use is  the law of total probability but I'm not sure. I'm trying to confirm it and will post when it's done.

Comment: Actually you don't even need the law of total probability but only the formula of conditional probability. I'll edit my post with this information.

Comment: I suppose conditional probability doesn't fit the problem. The probability of choosing full-time given/knowing female is different from the probability of choosing female and full-time. What do you think?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain further. The conditional probability is not the result but a value you need to find the result.